# Creating python Models for Datastore Entities

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-datastore, flask-login

My flask application uses datastore as a NOSQL database.

```
from flask import Flask, session,request,render_template
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.auth.transport import requests
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, UserMixin
import google.oauth2.id_token
import os


firebase_request_adapter = requests.Request()
db = datastore.Client()
login_manager = LoginManager()



app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = b'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

I'm trying to create a User model so I can use flask-login. I have not found the way to declare my model as I believe the Model is not a property of my datastore.client() variable.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  access_type = db.StringProperty()
```

How do I create my model?

Answer (score 1):

Datastore is a **NoSQL** (schemaless) database. It doesn't require you to create [kinds](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers) before using them - they will be created on the fly.

E.g.

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client()

user = datastore.Entity(client.key('Users'))
user.update({
    'name': 'John',
    'access_type': 'Test'
})
```

[Cloud Datastore Python API reference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/client.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [google-python-ndb](https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb) library gives you the ability to create models in Python